# Caption in a tikzpicture drawing

Tags: captions, tikz-styles, tikz-pic, tikz-graphdrawing

I have this LaTeX:
The `\caption` line at the end breaks the compilation.
How could I make this work?

Thanks

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt]
\draw [black] (18.1,-13.7) circle (3);
\draw (18.1,-13.7) node {$1$};
\draw [black] (18.1,-13.7) circle (2.4);
\draw [black] (38.6,-13.7) circle (3);
\draw (38.6,-13.7) node {$2$};
\draw [black] (38.6,-13.7) circle (2.4);
\draw [black] (58.6,-13.7) circle (3);
\draw (58.6,-13.7) node {$3$};
\draw [black] (58.6,-13.7) circle (2.4);
\draw [black] (10.6,-13.7) -- (15.1,-13.7);
\fill [black] (15.1,-13.7) -- (14.3,-13.2) -- (14.3,-14.2);
\draw [black] (21.1,-13.7) -- (35.6,-13.7);
\fill [black] (35.6,-13.7) -- (34.8,-13.2) -- (34.8,-14.2);
\draw (28.35,-14.2) node [below] {$\epsilon$};
\draw [black] (41.6,-13.7) -- (55.6,-13.7);
\fill [black] (55.6,-13.7) -- (54.8,-13.2) -- (54.8,-14.2);
\draw (48.6,-14.2) node [below] {$\epsilon$};
\draw [black] (57.277,-11.02) arc (234:-54:2.25);
\draw (58.6,-6.45) node [above] {$3$};
\fill [black] (59.92,-11.02) -- (60.8,-10.67) -- (59.99,-10.08);
\draw [black] (16.777,-11.02) arc (234:-54:2.25);
\draw (18.1,-6.45) node [above] {$1$};
\fill [black] (19.42,-11.02) -- (20.3,-10.67) -- (19.49,-10.08);
\draw [black] (37.277,-11.02) arc (234:-54:2.25);
\draw (38.6,-6.45) node [above] {$2$};
\fill [black] (39.92,-11.02) -- (40.8,-10.67) -- (39.99,-10.08);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{An NFA}
\end{center}
```

Comment: You might want to complete your minimal code. The community here is really big on that. You might also want to change the title into a question. Just pretend you are on jeopardy.

Comment: A common misunderstanding is that there's always a `floating` environment necessary. Use `\captionof` instead of `\caption` (requires the `caption` package)

Comment: Use \captionof{figure}{...} from the caption package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just throw the whole thing into a figure environment. Note that it will become a float, so it could float around a bit ;) You can use the standard parameters like `[!h]` for "stay put here" or `[!t]` for "try to stay up top" or `[!b]` for "try to stay down below" e.g. `\begin{figure}[!h]` For extreme measures you could get the `[H]` parameter by loading the `float` package. Another option would be to remove the float and use the `caption` package which adds `\captionof` command. You could wrap the whole thing in a `minipage` to keep the caption with the `tikz` picture. Floats might seem annoying, but they are usually better in longer documents, because LaTeX will try to place them where they are aesthetically better (it tries anyway—but you can help it with parameters).

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
...
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

And for tikz drawings, I usually also put them into a resizebox so that you can finely tune the width like you can with `\includeimage[width=.65\textwidth]`.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\resizebox{.65\textwidth}{!}{%
...
}%
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

Example with caption package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\tikzstyle{every node}+=[inner sep=0pt]
\draw [black] (18.1,-13.7) circle (3);
\draw (18.1,-13.7) node {$1$};
\draw [black] (18.1,-13.7) circle (2.4);
\draw [black] (38.6,-13.7) circle (3);
\draw (38.6,-13.7) node {$2$};
\draw [black] (38.6,-13.7) circle (2.4);
\draw [black] (58.6,-13.7) circle (3);
\draw (58.6,-13.7) node {$3$};
\draw [black] (58.6,-13.7) circle (2.4);
\draw [black] (10.6,-13.7) -- (15.1,-13.7);
\fill [black] (15.1,-13.7) -- (14.3,-13.2) -- (14.3,-14.2);
\draw [black] (21.1,-13.7) -- (35.6,-13.7);
\fill [black] (35.6,-13.7) -- (34.8,-13.2) -- (34.8,-14.2);
\draw (28.35,-14.2) node [below] {$\epsilon$};
\draw [black] (41.6,-13.7) -- (55.6,-13.7);
\fill [black] (55.6,-13.7) -- (54.8,-13.2) -- (54.8,-14.2);
\draw (48.6,-14.2) node [below] {$\epsilon$};
\draw [black] (57.277,-11.02) arc (234:-54:2.25);
\draw (58.6,-6.45) node [above] {$3$};
\fill [black] (59.92,-11.02) -- (60.8,-10.67) -- (59.99,-10.08);
\draw [black] (16.777,-11.02) arc (234:-54:2.25);
\draw (18.1,-6.45) node [above] {$1$};
\fill [black] (19.42,-11.02) -- (20.3,-10.67) -- (19.49,-10.08);
\draw [black] (37.277,-11.02) arc (234:-54:2.25);
\draw (38.6,-6.45) node [above] {$2$};
\fill [black] (39.92,-11.02) -- (40.8,-10.67) -- (39.99,-10.08);
\end{tikzpicture}
\captionof{figure}{My figure.}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This has put the drawing in a new page, at the middle of the page and after text that was typesetted _afterwards_

Comment: @johni See note about floats.